# Godot C# Running in the background

Tags: c#, multithreading, godot

I want a very expensive C# script to be running in the background while playing the main scene game.

As an example of the expected workflow of the code:

1. sleep 3 seconds
2. create and show an instance of a tilemap in the level scene
3. sleep 3 seconds
4. update the tilemap with some new sprites

The sleep times are never constant and cannot be known in advance: they are algorithms.

I want to avoid:

- Game hanging while the c# code is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running CPU-intensive code in a Task will prevent the main UI thread from locking up.

You should read Microsoft's [introduction to asynchronous based
programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming).

Here is an example of what I think you want:

```
    static async void DoHeavyWork()
    {
        //Starts a new Task that will NOT block the UI thread. 
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //This simulates the heavy task.
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //Run code on the UI thread here. 
            });
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        });
    }
```

If this was helpful I would appreciate it if you could mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: This lead to some information online - https://godotengine.org/qa/80078/c%23-awaiting-on-a-method-called-through-godot-object-call

Comment: I am getting error **Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke'**